# Angular 1.4.7 ng-if syntax issue

Tags: angularjs

Why this doesn’t work for my angular template view?

```
  <tr class="warning" ng-repeat="aIpacmTableLine in ipacmMacArray">
    <td><font color=SteelBlue>{{aIpacmTableLine}}</td>

    <td><font color=SteelBlue>
        <div ng-if="{{ipacmIpArray[$index]}} !== \"0.0.0.0\"">
            <a ng-href="{{ipacmIpArray[$index]}}">
                {{ipacmIpArray[$index]}}
            </a>
        </div>

        <div ng-if="{{ipacmIpArray[$index]}} === \"0.0.0.0\"">
            {{ipacmIpArray[$index]}}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

While this works

```
  <tr class="warning" ng-repeat="aIpacmTableLine in ipacmMacArray">
    <td><font color=SteelBlue>{{aIpacmTableLine}}</td>

    <td><font color=SteelBlue>
        <div>
            <a ng-href="{{ipacmIpArray[$index]}}">
                {{ipacmIpArray[$index]}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is in a template view html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interpolation directive `{{}}` would not work inside `ng-if/ng-show`, You should directly provide an expression to evaluate.

```
<div ng-if="ipacmIpArray[$index] !== '0.0.0.0'">
```